# list of all autoscaling groups whose scaling policy on CPU is below certain threshold in aws using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, autoscaling

i have bunch of ASGs want to use boto3 to get all ASG Names whose scaling policies on CPU are less than certain threshold (i.e All ASGs where scaling policies is set and value < 70)
for some reason getting only one asg and facing issue in appending to dict

````
client = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name='region_name')
response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()
#print(response)

# function to get all asg_names 
def get_asg_names():
    for asg_name in response['AutoScalingGroups']:
        asg_list = ((asg_name['AutoScalingGroupName']))
        #print(asg_list)
        get_scaling_policy_values(asg_list)

#print((asg_list))
asg_dict_map = dict()

def get_scaling_policy_values(asg_list):
    response2 = client.describe_policies(AutoScalingGroupName = asg_list)
    #print(response2)
    for policy_name in response2['ScalingPolicies']:
        asg_name_with_policy = policy_name['AutoScalingGroupName']
        target_value = policy_name['TargetTrackingConfiguration']['TargetValue']
        asg_dict_map[asg_names_with] =  asg_dict_map[target_value]
        #asg_dict_map['key'] = policy_name['AutoScalingGroupName']
        #asg_dict_map['value'] = policy_name['TargetTrackingConfiguration']['TargetValue']

get_asg_names()
print(asg_dict_map)```
````

Answer (score 1):

You would:

- Use `describe_auto_scaling_groups()` to obtain a list of Auto Scaling groups
- For each of them, call `describe_policies()` passing in the name of the Auto Scaling group
- Examine the configuration returned and perform your comparisons

Slightly modified version of your code:

```py
import boto3

asg_dict_map = dict()

client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
response = client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()

for asg in response['AutoScalingGroups']:
    asg_name = asg['AutoScalingGroupName']

    response2 = client.describe_policies(AutoScalingGroupName = asg_name)
    for policy in response2['ScalingPolicies']:
        policy_name = policy['AutoScalingGroupName']
        target_value = policy['TargetTrackingConfiguration']['TargetValue']
        asg_dict_map[policy_name] = target_value

print(asg_dict_map)
```

Comment: hey @john i have updated please see if you can help

Comment: The line `asg_dict_map[asg_names_with] =  asg_dict_map[target_value]` is attempting to access a value from `asg_dict_map` that does not yet exist. I think you mean to use: `asg_dict_map[asg_name_with_policy] = target_value`

Comment: but the dict is always is always returnign single item even though there are multiple ASG with scaling policies

Comment: I've added some updated code to my answer.

Comment: thank you so much @john works now had to add try excepe block in for loop